# Ruby on Rails: heroku run rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, precompile-assets

Please help me understand what `heroku run rake assets:precompile` exactly does. Ever since I began working on ruby on rails, I would always run these three commands before I push to github and heroku:

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

After I push to heroku, I would run:

`heroku run rake assets:precompile`

However, when I tried to run it after my last push to heroku, I got a bunch of the same errors on different files. For example:

`Warning. Error encountered while saving cache ... can't dump anonymous class ...`

To see if I can fix this, I ran

`heroku run rake assets:clean` and then `heroku run rake assets:precompile` again. The thing is that everything is working fine, but I just feel iffy having all these warnings/errors. Please help me understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

**Precompile**

To give you some clearer definitions - `Heroku` isn't the only system which requires you to "precompile" your assets. Asset precompilation is a pre-requisite of most Rails production environments, as it allows you to serve static assets (files) - perfect for speed & efficiency

Here's what the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) says about it:

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.
>
> During the precompilation phase an MD5 is generated from the contents
>   of the compiled files, and inserted into the filenames as they are
>   written to disc. These fingerprinted names are used by the Rails
>   helpers in place of the manifest name.

The reason why Heroku wants you to precompile your assets is because the Heroku environment is designed for speed & efficiency; and hence does not want to expend CPU power on compiling the assests for each request / instanace of your app

This means you have to either precompile the assets yourself, or let the [Heroku buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#default-buildpacks) sort that out for you

---

**Heroku**

As mentioned by `CWitty`, you'll want to make sure you compile your assets locally. And whilst I'm not sure about the errors you've received, I do know one thing: **precompilation populates the `public/assets` folder**

This means if you precompile locally *before* submitting to Heroku, you'll have all your latest assets present in your `public/assets` directory *before* you try and run the application on Heroku

Although Heroku does perform precompilation as part of the build process, you'll be much safer (from an exception perspective) by precompiling locally:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will give you the ability to populate the `public/assets` folder, allowing you to then push to Heroku without any issues

Comment: so I noticed doing `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and `rake assets:precompile` seem to be mutually exclusive, creating different files. I simply need to do run the production precompile command, then push? I've done that, but assets aren't showing. What else might be the problem?

Comment: excellent explanation, btw. Much better than the heroku articles.

Comment: What's the difference between `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 7):

You should be running this command before you push to Heroku as it **pre**compiles your assets. Heroku will automatically run this command if you are missing a *manifast.yml* file. After running `rake assets:precompile` locally you can commit all of the changes and then push to Heroku.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have an idea as to why I get the warnings? Are you suggesting I can ignore these?

Comment: I wouldn't ignore them. I just wouldn't run on once your code is on Heroku. I would do it prior to pushing to Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone having trouble figuring out why Heroku won't compile your assets automatically:

> If a public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not attempt to compile your assets. Rails 4 uses a file called public/assets/manifest-.json instead. On both versions you can generate this file by running $ rake assets:precompile locally and checking the resultant files into Git.

I found a `sprockets-manifest-*.json` and Heroku started compiling my assets automatically after I deleted this file.

In my case, this file was generated by the script `rails_composer`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any .jpeg make sure to change them to .jpg before compiling. The compile step will do it for you but your image_tags will be off if you're specifying your files with extensions.